# How to cleanse a system for a reinstall of Arduino IDE?

Tags: arduino, portability, arduino-ide, reinstall

I am trying to reinstall the Arduino IDE on my computer (Win 10) which had earlier used the same Arduino IDE version 1.6.0 (portable). I am now facing the issue of opening the IDE even.

This problem started when i installed the version Arduino 1.8.1 (non-portable). For certain reasons i want both the versions on my computer now. I have uninstalled 1.8.1(non-portable) and have put the portable version 1.8.1 in appropriate file directories. 1.8.1 exe runs perfectly but 1.6.0 exe still doesnt. Are there any ways to do so?

Comment: What is exactly problem? "doesn't work" ... isn't too informative

Comment: Arduino 1.6.0 launch throw a dialog box saying - "An Error occured while starting the application". Upon pressing the only button (OK) closes the dialog box.

Comment: By portable do you mean you have created a portable folder in the Arduino IDE installation folder as described in https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/PortableIDE? You may be able do get more information on the cause of the error by running arduino_debug.exe (which is located in the Arduino IDE installation folder) from the command line.